# GET request in Django Rest framework is not working with filter in the response JSON object

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Views.py

class UserPoints(ListAPIView):

```
 queryset = UserAttributes.objects.all()
 serializer_class = UserPointsSerializer
```

OR

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    UserAttributes = self.get_object(id)
    serializer = UserPointsSerializer(UserAttributes)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializers.py

class UserPointsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       username = serializers.Field(source='User')

```
class Meta:
    model = UserAttributes
    fields = [
        'points',
    ]
```

I want to get the point associated with a particular user when I send a GET Request with username as a parameter.

Comment: This code is a syntax error `UserAttributes = self.get_object(id)` you dont have to put a parameter id to self.get_object() since it already returns the object instance with the requested id instead use `self.get_object()` only. i suggest that you use `retrieve(self, request, pk=None)` method and not the `get(self, request):` if you are just calling one instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call .`is_valid()` on the serializer

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    user_attributes = UserAttribute.objects.get(id=id)
    serializer = UserPointsSerializer(data=user_attributes)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: but you can't use `is_valid()` unless you specifies the data option, must be `UserPointsSerializer(data=user_attributes)`